# Search and get double result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my PHP code which I used to search from database Mysql from PHPMyAdmin. But When I get the result it shows double. I didn't understand why it's double. If it's for 'foreach' loop then what will I use instead of that? 
Please help me out with the code.

```
<?Php

?>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
                @media print {
  #printPageButton {
    display: none;
  }
  #another {
      display: none;
  }
}
.border {
  border-style: double;
  border-color: blue;
}
</style>
<title>Demo of Search Keyword using PHP and MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>
<?Php
error_reporting(0);
include "config_1.php";
$todo=$_POST['todo'];
$search_text=$_POST['search_text'];
if(strlen($serch_text) > 0){
if(!ctype_alnum($search_text)){
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
}
if(isset($todo) and $todo=="search"){

$type=$_POST['type'];

$search_text=ltrim($search_text);
$search_text=rtrim($search_text);

    if($type<>"any"){
$query="select * from billbagnan where name='$search_text'";
        }
$count=$dbo->prepare($query);
$count->execute();
$no=$count->rowCount();
foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row){
echo "
<table class='border' style='text-align:center;'  width='900'>";
 echo "</td><td width='400' valign=top>";
echo " Full records here ";
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Institution</th></tr>";
foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row){
echo "<tr><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[instn]</td>
</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</td></tr></table>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are nesting a query within a query, so this will most likely produce multiple tables with all of the data.  You are also executing the query 3 times (once prepared an 2 using `query()`).

Instead run the query once (the `prepare()` and `execute()`) and if there are rows, loop over the result...

```
// If there are rows
if ($count->rowCount() > 0 ) {
    echo "<table class='border' style='text-align:center;'  width='900'>";
    echo "</td><td width='400' valign=top>";
    echo " Full records here ";
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Institution</th></tr>";
    // Loop over rows and display data
    while ( $row = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

You are also using prepare and execute, but not using bind variables, so you should really be using...

```
if($type<>"any"){
    $query="select * from billbagnan where name=?";
    $count=$dbo->prepare($query);
    $count->execute([$search_text]);
}
else {
    $query="select * from billbagnan";
    $count=$dbo->prepare($query);
    $count->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind information. But I solved it in my own way. Anyway thanks again.